# Suddenly Getting an Error in my Excel VBA- when Saving as .xls FileFormat:=53

Tags: excel, vba

This code has been working for months, and today it is throwing the error:

Run-Time Error '1004'
Method 'SaveAs' of Object '_Workbook' failed

The line of code causing the error is:

```
        '~~>. Save the file
        .SaveAs Filename:="\\MY\File\Path\Report_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd") & ".xls", FileFormat:=53
```

I dont know what has changed here for this suddenly not to work, any ideas?

I am running MS Excel 2016, Version 1609

There is no file in that location with the same name.

I want to save as an .xls in case anyone we send this to has an older version of Excel, I could change it to an .xlsx and rewrite the code a bit but I am curious why all of the sudden this errored out?

Thanks for looking.

Comment: I have just changed the section of code:

    Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
to
    "TEST"

and it worked- I have looked in the file location and removed all files that are there, placing the date code back in the I get the same error. Is there a chance a phantom file exists that I cant see?

Comment: Since you just proved you have permissions to write to the directory (using your "Report_TEST" filename), the problem is more likely that you're forcing an extension of `.xls` when the `FileFormat:=53` is for a macro-enabled workbook (extension `.xlsm`).

Comment: I am getting the same error with format 56 though?

Answer (score 0):

I think to save as ".xls", FileFormat should be 56
http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
53 works with "TEST" and . I tried 56 and still no luck. I think there is a phantom file hanging out somewhere that i cant see. I think I need to Write in on "On Error" add "1" to the end of the file name, on that error add "2", etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the macro recorder for this. This is what mine produces:

```
ChDir "C:\Users\gropc\Desktop"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\uname\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

The format should be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a hidden file issue you could exploit `FileSystemObject` object and loop until you find a "free" file name

so your code line could become the following:

```
.SaveAs fileName:=GetFreeFileName("\\MY\File\Path\Report_" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd"), ".xls")
```

which uses the following function:

```
Function GetFreeFileName(fileName As String, fileExt As String)
    Dim iFile As Long

    With CreateObject("FileSystemObject")
        Do While .FileExists(fileName & fileExt)
            iFile = iFile + 1
            fileName = fileName & "-" & iFile
        Loop
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: That looks like what I need, I'll give this a go- Many Thanks!